# Is it possible to pass data from an angular7 component or service to index.html file?

Tags: angular

I am trying to define an object with dynamic data in index.html file of an Angular7 application. Can I send and update data in index.html while the angular application is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign an `id` to the element. Then obtain the element using `getElementById('id')` and assign data to it.

index.html

```
<my-app>loading</my-app>
<div id="indexDiv">/div>
```

Component

```
document.getElementById('indexDiv').innerHTML = "Updated from component"
```