# Angular : serve a dynamic index.html

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

Today, we are working with AngularJS and Asp.Net Web API (therefore not Core) and we wish to evolve towards Angular (using hybrid mode). Our server serves index.hbs (handlebars) in which some files are dynamic, depending on certain parameters.

```
    <link rel="icon" href="{{Config.IconUrl}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{Config.CssUrl}}">
```

Problem: with Angular, the index is now on the client side, so the application does not know the css file during startup. How can I keep the same operation as before?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think passing dynamic values to index.html is the correct way to do it. Nevertheless you could adopt my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60431113/6513921).

1. Assign IDs to the tags.

```
<my-app>loading</my-app>
<link rel="icon" id="icons_link">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="css_link">
```

2. Obtain the elements by IDs in the component and assign the required href property values.

```
document.getElementById('icons_link').href = "link URL here"
document.getElementById('css_link').href = "link URL here"
```